# Handle form in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was reading this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
and i have a question: beside `HandleForm` method shouldn't be `httpPost` attribute? I thought default action handle only get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be there. `HttPost` can be used as restriction, but also it can be omitted.

If there are two HandleForm methods, then one of them need to have such attribute to distinguish them. But if there is only one method, then it shouldn't matter.

It's like `HttpGet` attribute. You also can specify it, but as usual you don't do it, and it used by default. And if there are two methods. You can specify either `HttpGet` on one method, or `HttpPost` on another method, so ASP.Net MVC can differentiate them